# Random errors appear in alert emails - how could this happen?

Tags: php, mysql, email, lamp

I'm the webmaster and lead developer for a set of websites providing assessment services. I have no background in server administration and am ashamed to say that being a sysadmin is pretty intimidating to me; I'm comfortable with basic command line, but I'm frequently overwhelmed by all of the myriad configurations needed to get a standard LAMP stack working with several subdomains and an email server running.

I've finally reached something that thoroughly stumps me. Let me first list our basic server configuration:

- VPS running Ubuntu 12.04
- Standard Apache, PHP, Mysql, BIND services
- 1 main domain + 4 subdomain websites configured in the above services, two of which make extensive use of mysql databases having 300-400 tables each
- Citadel email server (a choice I'm increasingly come to see as a mistake)
- Swiftmailer (for sending automated emails from PHP)

Some of our pages (relating to account and assessment management) send alert emails to the test taker, coach, and/or us, when a specific action is taken. The text for these emails is fetched from a "boilerplate" table in the mysql db. Then in PHP, a couple "placeholder" tags are swapped out for test taker name, date, etc. The PHP code then uses Swift Mailer to send the prepared text as an email, with our local Citadel email server, to a given set of (usually external) addresses. We are CC'd on most of these emails, to provide us with a second record of all of the automated messages we've sent.

(Feel free to skip over this) Here's the gist of my code that fetches and processes the text, and sends it as an email:

```
$subject = $bp['email_report_title'];
$subject = str_replace("[NAME]", $name, $subject);
$subject = str_replace("[INSTRUMENT_NAME]", $instrument_name, $subject);

$body = $bp['email_report'];
$body = str_replace("[NAME]", $name, $body);
$body = str_replace("[INSTRUMENT_NAME]", $instrument_name, $body);
$body = str_replace("[INSTRUMENT_BASE]", $instrument_base, $body);

sendEmail($email_to, $email_from, $email_cc, $subject, $body);
```

In a nutshell, here's my problem:  the emails we see (as a result of the above events) *sometimes* have typos appear in them -- inconsistently. Here are a couple images as example, showing a set of auto emails generated & sent on the *same* day using the *same* PHP code drawing from the *same* (unaltered) string in our database. These are screenshots from our internal (CC'd) account, viewed in Mac Mail; but based on test taker complaints, all email recipients appear to be seeing the same text. In the first image, note the differences in spacing in the titles.

In the second & third images, note the incorrect link (two periods at the end). I have checked the PHP code and the mysql source text, and can find absolutely no reason that the login link would be changed to have two periods in that spot. **EDIT:** Based on commenter request, I've copied the full-length email text below the images.

[image: Alert email titles: note inconsistent spacing in the "ready to view" text]
[image: Alert email content: what the login link SHOULD look like]
[image: Alert email content: what the login link OCCASIONALLY looks like]

> [name removed]'s LSUA report has been completed. To view the report, click on the following link: 
>   https://www.devtestservice.org/security/logIn..php
>
> Once you have logged in, click the LSUA icon, and follow the link that says "View your report".
>
> The commenting on our assessments is done by highly trained human beings who occasionally make mistakes. If you notice any inconsistencies or errors in your report, please let us know and we will make prompt repairs. If you have any problems logging in or viewing your report, please contact us using the following link: 
>   https://www.devtestservice.org/contactus.php
>
> ---
>
> Lectica, Inc. 
>   Northampton, MA 01060
>
> Our mission is to develop standardized, formative, and diagnostic developmental assessments of the knowledge and skills required to meet the challenges of the 21st century. Our aims are threefold: (1) to build engaging, educative, and feedback-rich developmental assessments and learning resources for K-18 students and their teachers, (2) to create equally rich assessments that diagnose learning needs and support the development of adults (in the workplace and beyond), and (3) to build (and share) knowledge about learning and its role in the future of society.
>
> This message contains PRIVILEGED AND CONFIDENTIAL INFORMATION intended solely for the use of the addressee(s) named above. Any disclosure, distribution, copying or use of the information by others is strictly prohibited. If you have received this message in error, please advise the sender by immediate reply and delete the original message and any and all attachments. Thank you.

Sorry for the long background explanation. But **my question** is simple: **How could these typos happen?** At what point in the workflow could a (verified consistent) mysql data cell, fetched and processed by (straightforward) PHP code, plopped into a standard PHP -> SMTP mailer plugin, lead to the creation of an email that appears to have random typos?

I'd love any ideas you have, and I'm glad to provide more detailed code if needed. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Thanks to Eggyal for pointing out that only the longer subject lines have the spaces removed. This pattern holds true across other older emails too. Also, I've provided the full text of one email alert above; note the '..php' at the end of the link. All emails have the same signature line, and all alert emails of the same type have the same length body (plus or minus 15 characters for different instrument names and test taker names).

Comment: compare the template text against the final result of all those replace operations, BEFORE you send the emails. make sure the typos aren't appearing at the PHP level. If you never see a typo in PHP, then start looking at the mail server, but I'd consider it highly unlikely that a mail client (or server) would randomly add/remove `.` characters.

Comment: Thanks @MarcB. Not sure if I've made this clear in the above background explanation, but I think I'm proficient enough in PHP to verify that PHP typos couldn't be creating this. The PHP code I copied above is all of the PHP code that processed the template text. The text you see in brackets (like "[NAME]") are the only parts of the template text that are altered by PHP replaces. That code is definitely not responsible for the random addition of the dot, since str_replace's only behavior is a global replace. Also, the "two dots" thing is very inconsistent -- it has only happened twice so far.

Comment: What does the `sendEmail` function look like? Also, which version of SwiftMailer?

Comment: @pilsetnieks, the sendEmail function is a simple procedure to do the following: a) ensure email addresses are present and valid (Swift freaks out if format is wrong), b) create a Swift SMTP transport & mailer instance, and c) send the message through Swift. The function is built off of Swift's howto docs <http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html>. Oddly enough, when I look in my Swift plugin I don't see any version info... but I set up Swift around March 2012.

Comment: I think that the problem exhibited in your first image (spacing corruption) is almost certainly due to folding of long subject lines - view the raw email to verify.  As for the addition of additional periods, viewing the raw email might again help to see what's going on - but showing us the relevant part of the template from the database could also help.

Comment: Eggyal: BRILLIANT. I wish I'd spotted that. Looking back at older emails, the longer subject lines do appear to have that problem. I wish you'd written this in answer form, because it's a good candidate for the bounty...

Comment: By asking for (the relevant part of) *the template from the database*, I was trying to ascertain whether the URL (that ultimately becomes `..php`) was in the template itself, or was some field that is replaced/manipulated/inserted into the email when sending?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @eggyal. Yes, the link shown is part of the original email body template itself - it's not "swapped in" by PHP code.

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced very similar behavior in emails when using plain php's mail() function and postfix smtp server. It took me weeks to figure it out why HTML in those emails is randomly corrupted: it was long lines in the email source, exactly as @eggyal writes in the comments.

[RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-2.1.1) states that lines should be no more than 78 chars. To comply, SMTP server inserts newlines at selected places, however this can easily corrupt space-sensitive content. Check the Content-Transfer-Encoding header in your emails, I assume it will be either 7bit, 8bit or quoted printable.
Try changing it to base64 - that's the easy way. I'm not familiar with Swift Mailer but I guess this could work:

```php
$transferEncoding = $message->getHeaders()->get('Content-Transfer-Encoding');
$transferEncoding->setValue('base64');
```

Alternatively, you can try to wrap lines manually before handing over to SMTP server.

Comment: I had the same problem with automatically inserted new lines. But this would not explain the **disappearing** of spaces, but only the **appearing** ...

Comment: Thanks @Jirka. In your experience, could this explain the "extra period" issue I'm having with links? After all, at least the subject weird spacing thing doesn't "break" any functionality of the email, it just looks ugly.

As I mentioned to Eggyal above, the problematic link is part of the email template itself; it is not "swapped in" by PHP code. Also note that the link appears right after a newline, so I don't believe the link itself would be "wrapping" when SMTP gets its grubby hands on it. However, note that the live *above* the link is wrapping several times. I'll try correcting that.

Comment: @Jirka, you've provided the best lead I've got so the bounty is yours. Thanks for the ideas.

Comment: Whoops, sorry for late reply. That extra dot is still a mystery to me. Wrapping only inserts newlines or spaces but not never characters. It does not look like any kind of URL sanitation either. I'd suggest to check what's going out of SwiftMailer, or use another SMTP for debugging - to track which one causes it.